# FIM Synchronization Service doesn't start

Tags: synchronisation, forefront

Having problems with FIM Sychronization Service, its fails to start with following message in Application logs

> The server encountered an unexpected error and stopped.    "BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   sql.cpp(8490): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported
>   values.) BAIL: MMS(9948): sql.cpp(8533): 0x80231334 (The sql
>   connection string has unsupported values.) BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   server.cpp(260): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has unsupported
>   values.) BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860): 0x80231334 (The sql
>   connection string has unsupported values.) BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   service.cpp(1539): 0x80231334 (The sql connection string has
>   unsupported values.) ERR: MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating
>   com objects. Error code: -2145184972. This is retry number 0. BAIL:
>   MMS(9948): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022  ERR:
>   MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 1. BAIL: MMS(9948): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022  ERR:
>   MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 2. BAIL: MMS(9948): clrhost.cpp(283): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   scriptmanagerimpl.cpp(7670): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948):
>   server.cpp(251): 0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948): server.cpp(3860):
>   0x80131022  BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1539): 0x80131022  ERR:
>   MMS(9948): service.cpp(988): Error creating com objects. Error code:
>   -2146234334. This is retry number 3. BAIL: MMS(9948): service.cpp(1002): 0x80131022

We are running on Dec 12 CU patch.
Checked the registry keys at following location, looks all the keys have correct values

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FIMSynchronizationService\Parameters
```

The service is running under farm administrator account, it is added in the local administrators as well (for the time being, just to provision UPS).

Ran Process Monitor for any Access Violations but it came neat.

Searched all around, nothing helped, please help if anybody has faced such issue before?

Not sure why the service doesn't log detailed information in some log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed Client Configuration Utility for SQL Server for checking the network protocol as somebody had mentioned in a forum (both TCP, namedpipe were enabled). This required a reboot.

Again went in Central Administration, tried running Synchronization Service, failed checked the event logs and found following message

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob
>   (ID 23f8c125-f4f5-45a4-8180-576478fdeffd) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below. An update conflict has occurred, and
>   you must re-try this action.  The object
>   ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance was updated by
>   DOMAIN\ADMIN_Farm, in the OWSTIMER (2576) process, on machine
>   APPSERVER001.blah.com.   View the tracing log for more information
>   about the conflict.Checked the ULS Viewer found following

Found multiple errors from owtimer.exe but this one was a good indication

> ConcurrencyException: Old Version : 49462 New Version : 49502

and this one

> ProfileSynchronizationService: Provisioning TImer Job encountered an
>   exception:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException: An
>   update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The
>   object ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance was updated by
>   DOMAIN\ADMIN_Farm, in the OWSTIMER (2576) process, on machine
>   APPSERVER001.blah.com.  View the tracing log for more information
>   about the conflict.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.StoreObject(SPPersistedObject
>   obj, Boolean storeClassIfNecessary, Boolean ensure)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.PutObject(SPPersistedObject
>   persistedObject, Boolean ensure)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance
>   profileSyncInstance)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationSetupJob.Execute(SPJobState
>   state)

We had applied the CU recently and ran the configuration wizard as well, but seemed somehow all the components were not updated.

Ran the SharePoint Configuration Wizard till the time it brings the central admin, chose the manual option and exited the screen.

Went to the services page, tried starting the service again and it worked this time.

Comment: i was going to suggest that i had a similar looking error on a site when the upgrade hadn't committed, if you took a look under the database status screen in central admin it might have repoted that the user profile databases required upgrading.